# Django: Difference between User.objects.profile.all() and User.objects.get_profile()?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a UserProfile model with related_name='profile' for the User FK.

Let's say I have a User obj, user1. If I want to get the UserProfile object from the user1, what is the difference between using user1.profile.all() and user1.get_profile() in terms of db hits and efficiency?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither of these commands is actually valid in Django. However, if you fix the syntax issues, they do completely different things.

If you want to get both the User instance and its associated Profile in one go, with a single db hit, you would use this:

```
user = User.objects.select_related('profile').get(pk=my_pk_value)
```

Now you can access the profile from the `user` by doing `user.profile`, and you don't incur another db hit. You can do exactly the same if you miss out `select_related`, but it will incur another db hit.

If you *already* have a User object `user`, you would do `user.get_profile()`, and that gets you the actual Profile object - with another db hit.