# How to get user object by profile field value

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

Here is how to get user with related profile: [Django: Difference between User.objects.profile.all() and User.objects.get_profile()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253926/django-difference-between-user-objects-profile-all-and-user-objects-get-profil)

But this example is using user id. I want to get user by `activation_key` which is in UserProfile object, I try something like:

```
UserProfile.objects.select_related('user').get(activation_key=key)
```

but I am getting:

> UserProfile matching query does not exist.

Comment: Are you sure there is a UserProfile with `activation_key=key`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
user = User.objects.get(userprofile__activation_key='key')
```

Answer (score 2):

If what you are trying to do is to obtain the django.contrib.auth.models.User object associated with your UserProfile like the following example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    activation_key = models.CharField(...)
```

What I would do is:

```
user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(activation_key='some_key')
user = user_profile.user
```

Hope that was what you are looking for